# Change mysql default engine to innoDB on hostgator?

Tags: mysql, innodb, web-hosting, myisam, storage-engines

Hello guys I just finished building my website using php slim 3 framework and I bought a domain and hosting everything is okay but I have only one problem that I can't fix.

When I built my website on my localhost I used the innoDB storage engine for mysql on hostgator they used the MYISAM storage engine as a default storage engine I want to change it to innoDB cause there is no support for foreign keys in MYISAM.

My hosting plan is the shared hosting (baby plan) it appears that innoDB is compatible with my hosting plan I contacted the hostgator support team to solve the problem they told me sorry this is such a programming problem which is out of our scope.

I don't know what to do please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Create Table` statement has `ENGINE` attribute.  If you set  ENGINE=INNODB, MySQL will use InnoDB as an engine for that table.  You may also run `ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE=INNODB`

Comment: I tried to do so and yeah I get dropdowns to select the reference id but I can still drop tables even if they have a foreign key with another table which is wrong

Comment: I don't know what interface to MySQL is provided by hotgator but if you are able to run SQL, you can do `Alter Table`.  No need to drop tables.

Comment: I have created each table from the beginning specifying it's engine , character set and collate but the tables could be dropped even if they have a foreign key constraints on them